# Compile failure for Boost SSL

Tags: c++, boost, ssl

i want to use

```
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
```

but it ever drops me this:

```
1>d:\boost\boost\asio\ssl\detail\openssl_types.hpp(19) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/conf.h': No such file or directory
```

whats wrong with it?

Comment: can you locate a file by that name somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`boost::asio::ssl` requires `OpenSSL`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html

**OpenSSL is required to make use of Boost.Asio's SSL support.**

Check configuration of `boost::asio` library and configuration of `openssl`.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to install OpenSSL http://www.openssl.org/source/

Answer (score 0):

You need OpenSSl.

Follow this link : https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

You have a list of automatic intaller for Openssl on Windows !!

Choose "Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2d". Install it to your system and add the needed path to the lib to your project configuration.

Re-compile everything and it will work.

(Paths to add are : XXXX/OpenSSL-Win32\include and XXXX/OpenSSL-Win32\lib)