# Compile failure for Boost SSL in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, kdevelop

I have the same problem as in [Compile failure for Boost SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955443/compile-failure-for-boost-ssl). However I was not able to resolve it from the answer provided. I have `openssl` installed in my `Ubuntu14` system. The IDE used is `kDevelop`.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `libssl-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

In future, please search headers you need by [packages.ubuntu.com resource](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=openssl%2Fconf.h&mode=&suite=trusty&arch=any).

Comment: I installed in the same way

Comment: What is the output of `locate openssl/conf.h` then ?

Comment: /home/MYPC/openssl-1.0.1j/include/openssl/conf.h
/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/conf.h

Comment: You installed it in the wrong path: it should be in `/usr/include/` or `/usr/local/include`, or any other system includepath. Specially for this case with openssl you may move or copy files from `/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl` to `/usr/include/openssl` and it will solve your problem.